# Meaning of "tightness around somebody's mouth"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of:

> seeing tightness around sb's mouth

It's an expression I've seen in *A Song of Ice and Fire*. For example:

> Bowen Marsh was angry. Jon could see it in his eyes, **the tightness around his mouth**, the flush to those round cheeks. That red is not from cold. "Please sit," he said.

More context can be found [here](http://fnovels.com/a-dance-with-dragons-page-105.html).

Comment: From the OP's "asoiaf" we were supposed to understand it to mean "A Song of Ice and Fire"? Wow, I am seriously getting old. LOTR move over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an English expression as much as an image expressed in English.  The *muscles* around the character's mouth are *tight* (meaning "contracted), as if he's [*biting back*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+back) angry words.

This facial expression doesn't always convey anger, although it usually conveys some negative emotion like *disapproval*, *discomfort*, *disgust*, and so on, which, I think, is more or less the same in any language.

Comment: "His lips were pursed in disapproval"